# Automating QC to find corrupt video files

Tags: video-quality, automation, analysis

I have a hundred of visually (!) corrupt video clips in H.264 'hiding' within a larger set of files.
As they have been re-transcoded, all of them are now **technically** OK and will play fine, but will have green flash on every other frame.

I have noticed that if I run a file through QCTools then I can identify them by the 'temporal outliers' value, as every other frame is drastically different from the previous one (because of those green flashes).

I would like to point QCTools to each file in this large set, but only:

- process a small portion of it - there is no time to go through every file in its entire duration
- fetch only one value - temporal outliers

I have looked through the help of the QCTools CLI version and could not find a way to do this. Does anyone have any other ideas on identifying these files? Is there still a way to do this with QCTools?

Comment: If a file is corrupt, is it corrupt throughout the video stream, or are there good portions within?

Comment: If memory serves, QCTools mostly just wraps ffmpeg commands, so you might be able to figure out which ffmpeg command calculates the temporal outliers value and automate that.

Comment: @MichaelLiebman Excellent idea, I will have a look for ffmpeg filter that does the job and will post it here if I find something. Thank you!

Comment: Green flash sounds like it could be gpu decode bug. Check the files on another machine to make sure they’re actually corrupt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since QCTools wraps the ffmpeg/ffprobe and uses the signalstats filter, here is how to achieve what I wanted:

```
ffprobe -f lavfi movie="Bad.mp4","signalstats=tout" -read_intervals %00:01 -show_frames
```

**-show_frames** outputs the frame summary into STDOUT. It contains the value that I need:

> TAG:lavfi.signalstats.TOUT=0

**-read_intervals** allows me to process only a small part of the file to get signal stats from only a small portion of the file

We can also check how QCTools does it by looking at the source code here:
https://github.com/bavc/qctools/blob/master/Source/GUI/BigDisplay.cpp#L844-L845